# Package biblatex Error: File '"FILENAME".bbl' not created by biblatex. \begin{document}

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, errors, packages

I an new to LaTeX.. My question is about the error I get

> Package biblatex Error: File '"FILENAME".bbl' not created by biblatex.
>   \begin{document}.

I have tried to read the guide to `biblatex` but I cannot find the mistake in my own code.. Anybody has an idea of the problem? I will provide all necessary info if you can help me.
I am trying to add the bibliography, but it seems a quite tough task -.-

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Remove the offending file and run biber (or bibtex) again.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I tried also to reinstall the whole package!! It works now. Thanks again

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This error happens when there is a `.bbl` file created by BibTeX for a previous version of the document, when `biblatex` was not loaded.

Since the `.bbl` file is generated by Biber or BibTeX, you should remove it and run the appropriate program (Biber, if you use the standard setting for `biblatex`); this operation will generate a new `.bbl` file according to `biblatex` wishes.

See [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-in-a-nutshell-for-beginners)